# Can faces of one object be selected by the shape of another object?

Tags: modeling

A shape created using the ant-landscape plugin looks like this: (selection is another sphere):

[image]

I tried to incorporate the *Boolean Modifier* but found no solution.
How could the highlighted areas be selected?
I also tried to select the hilly areas with *Select/Sharp Edges* but this would switch to vertex selection.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Using Vertex Groups with Data Transfer modifier**

Assign all the vertices of the sphere to **Vertex Group** with value of 1 and scale the sphere to very small size.

Create a vertex group and add DataTransfer modifier to the landscape object.

Then in the modifier select the sphere as **Source Object**, enable **Vertex Data** using **Vertex Group(s)** and set **Vertex Mapping** to **Projected Face Interpolated.**

[image]

**2. Using Vertex Groups with VertexWeightMix modifier and spherical blend texture.**

Create a Vertex Group with a value of 1 on all vertices of the landscape object.

Then add VertexWeightMix modifier, in the modifier select created vertex group in **Vertex Groups A and B**, set **Mix Mode** to **Difference** and create a new Texture Mask with Use Channel set to **Value**.

Then open texture settings, change Type to **Blend**, in Colors enable Ramp, set interpolation between color stops to **Constant** and Blend Progression change to **Spherical**.

Change to Weight Paint mode and adjust the texture color ramp till you get desired result.

[image]

[image]

**3. Weight Paint mode with Transferring Weights to active object.**

*May not be as precise as previous methods but quicker to setup.*

Assign all the vertices of the sphere to Vertex Group with value of 1.

Then in object mode select the sphere and holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> button select landscape object and switch to Weight Paint mode.

While in Weight Paint mode create a Vertex Group and in Tools tab click **Transfer Weights** button, then in Operator panel change Data Type to **Vertex Group(s)** and Vertex Mapping to **Projected Face Interpolated** and adjust Max Distance to get desired result.

[image]